# How to bind a widget to a Virtuell Event

Tags: events, tcl, tk-toolkit

I want so register multiple widgets to one virtual event. This is the idea of the code. But I do not find out,  how I can send down from the toplevel "." to any widgets, where the virtual event is registered.

```
 1  #!/bin/sh
 2  # \
 3          exec tclsh "$0" "$@"


 4  package require Tk
 5  proc send { } {
 6      puts "send event"
 7      event generate ***HERE IS MY PROBLEM *** <<TEST>>
 8  }

 9  label .l1 -text label1
10  label .l2 -text label2
11  button .b1 -text event -command send

12  bind .l1 <<TEST>> {puts "here 1"}
13  bind .l2 <<TEST>> {puts "here 2"}

14  grid .l1 
15  grid .l2
16  grid .b1
```

Found this solution:

```
 7      event generate . <<TEST>>
...
14  set tags [bindtags .]
15  bindtags . [list {*}$tags .l1 .l2]
```

Will be there a house keeping necessary after "destroy .l1" ?

Comment: Hmm, this is reversed from the way that events are usually directed.

Comment: @DonalFellow: can you please explain more on that. Does this mean, my solution is not common? What would be better?